# lump numeric values to totals within a range in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, formula, excel-2010

Given a column of numeric values, is it possible to sum values until the total reaches a particular threshhold, then reset the sum total and continue? for example

```
Val Sum
103 
52  155
47  
60  
103 210
100 
76  176
163 163
169 169
87  
103 190
84  
31  
59  174
87  
49  
67  203
```

This sums groups of numbers until the value exceeds 150, then resets the counter.

Comment: Do you mind if the solution is in VBA or do you want to stick to formulas?

Comment: Maybe we could deal with this with array formula, can't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do it (no need for array formulas let alone VBA):

In B2, type `=IF(B1<150,B1+A2,A2)` and drag down. This will sum until it reaches 150 or more, and then restart at zero. Of course, the intermediate sums (i.e. on the way up to 150) will show as well. If this bothers you, a couple of options spring to mind:

- Type `=IF(B2>=150,B2,"")` in C2 and drag down, and hide column B.
- Apply conditional formatting to column B such that numbers below 150 get shown in white font.

Comment: really nice, simple answer. I expanded it a little, but you got me 90% of the way there. =IF(B1+A2<150,B1+A2,0) in the second column and =IF(B3=0,B2+A3,0) in the third to just get the values > 150.

Comment: “Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.” Leonardo da Vinci. I should have thought of something simplier :) (i must admit i always try to find solutions without intermediate values)

Answer (score 2):

i'll post it more for the **proof of concept** than a real answer or for the case i could improve this (Issun may have an idea too).

Here it is:
Let assume your Val is in `column A` and Sum in `column B` and Titles are in `row 1`.
In `column C`, we will set a formula that will tell which is the "last" cell where you sumed it up > in cell `C3`, put:

```
{=MAX(IF($B$2:B2=0;0;ROW($B$2:B2)))}
```

This is an array formula, you will have to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In cell `B3`, you will have to put the first value (155 in your example), sorry, i didn't find a proper workaround.
In cell `B4`, put:

```
=IF(SUM($A$1:A4)-SUM(INDIRECT("$B$1:"&ADDRESS(C4;2)))>150;SUM($A$1:A4)-SUM(INDIRECT("$B$1:"&ADDRESS(C4;2)));0)
```

Then drag & drop the formulas till the end of your values.

**[EDIT]** Actually, you could put it all in a single formula in cell `B2`:

```
{=IF(SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM(INDIRECT("$B$1:"&ADDRESS(MAX(IF($B$1:B1=0;0;ROW($B$1:B1)));2)))>150;SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM(INDIRECT("$B$1:"&ADDRESS(MAX(IF($B$1:B1=0;0;ROW($B$1:B1)));2)));0)}
```

and drag and drop it till the end of your values. Seems to work too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. not sure if it works, because a more simple answer got me 90% of the way to the answer, but +1 for the effort.

Comment: Jean-François's answer is mucher clearer, thanks for the upvote though.

Comment: Thanks, but +1 to you for the scary single-formula solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in VBA (sorry I know you wanted a forumula). You can obviously tweat the range to be whatver you need it to be. Please note I used LONG as data type (and I am casting to long to avoid some errors), but you need to use DOUBLE if you have any floating point numbers.

```vb
Sub SumIt()

Dim cell As range
Dim currentCount As Long

For Each cell In range("A2:A100")
    currentCount = currentCount + CLng(cell.Value)
    If currentCount > 150 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = currentCount
        currentCount = 0
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**How it works**: I loop through each cell in the range and add the value to a variable called currentCount. I then check if it's over 150, if it is I paste the currentCount to the B column (same row) and reset the count and move to the next cell. Simple!

Comment: You're very welcome and thanks for the upvote! Maybe you can see why I prefer to go VBA with everything these days - code like this is so much easier to read and alter. Then again, formulas are fast and you don't need to worry about macro settings for other users that might use your workbook. :)